# Looping through all the files for specific system date - C#

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I am trying to copy all the files for a specific system date from a directory to another directory. However, all the files get copied and not just for a specified date. 
If we assume files are under `c:\testfiles\`

```
Date_Modified            Name 
2/14/2020 5:00 AM        txt_1.csv
2/14/2020 5:30 AM        txt_2.csv 
2/14/2020 6:00 AM        txt_3.csv 
2/13/2020 6:00 AM        txt_4.csv 
2/13/2020 6:15 AM        txt_5.csv
```

The code below should fetch the most recent date, which is `2/14/2020` here, and loop through the files only for `2/14`. But this code is picking up `2/13` files as well.

```
// this gives me the latest date.
DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(LatestFile);
DateTime dateonly = dt.Date;

// this is the code which I assumed would loop through only 2/14, but it is looping through all files. 
 var latestFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourcepath).Where(x => new FileInfo(x).CreationTime.Date == dt.Date);
                foreach (string s in latestFiles)
                {

                     string destfile = targetPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                     System.IO.File.Copy(s, destfile, true);
                }
```

How can I copy only files for 2/14 to another directory? I have to look for the most recent date and copy all the files for that date into another directory.

what is it that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `LastWriteTime` rather than `CreationTime`?

Comment: `Date_Modified` != `CreationTime`

Comment: @Enigmativity.. I would like to get all the files for latest date in a directory.. i am very new to c# and not sure which one to use.

Comment: All files have 3 dates (Creation, Access, Write in `dir` command terms) which you can see by using `dir * /t:C` or `dir * /t:A` or `dir * /t:W`). Look at that information and figure out what do you mean "the latest date" - [edit] post afterward to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see the dates are different for latest file you are taking GetLastWriteTime and comparing with CreationTime

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = "c:/test"; //Create the directory with some files
        var latestFile = "c:/test/test2.txt"; // Name of one file which is in c:/test
        var targetPath = "c:/test2"; //Create the directory

        Directory.GetFiles(path)
            .Where(e => File.GetLastWriteTime(e).Date.Equals(File.GetLastWriteTime(latestFile).Date))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(e =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Copying {e}");
                File.Copy(e, Path.Join(targetPath, Path.GetFileName(e)), true);
            });
    }
```